# Section Title and Paragraph text overlapping in ACM Sig Alternate using Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, acm

I am trying to create a simple document using the ACM Sig Alternate Template obtained from [here](https://www.um.edu.mt/__data/assets/file/0006/395628/ACM_paper_template.zip). After removing the boilerplate copyright text, the text after Section Titles (such as the Introduction) is overlapping with the title. I am using Overleaf to render the document.

Image is shown below:

[image]

Am I doing something incorrectly?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\begin{document}
\title{Testing}

\numberofauthors{3}
%
\author{
    John Doe\\
       \email{john.doe@testing.com}
}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
test code
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
fish farms

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{sigproc} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\hfill\\ ` under each `\section{...}` solves the issue, but it feels like a cheat. I still haven't solved the issue itself.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. Please add the `.log ` file to our question to help identify the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with the sig-alternate-per template from ACM as well. In the cls file I changed the section definition that for me is

```latex
\def\section{%
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-10\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -2\p@}% GM
    {4\p@}{\baselineskip 14pt\secfnt\@ucheadtrue}%
}
```

The problem is `{4\p@}` that identifies the points after the section title. If you set it like at 14 it will be good to go and the text won't overlap the title anymore. The same change has to be done for the other subsections, etc.

I can't test on your class because the link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Man that did it I knew it was in the cls file but as someone who just uses it for university very rarely I wasn't sure what dictates the formatting. Just made the account to thank you! I can't directly reply bc of the new account.